# How do I install Indicator Synapse in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, indicator

[image: Synapse indicator demo]

I am in love with the **synapse spotlight indicator** and I noticed that none of the PPA offers a working version for 16.04. I have tried the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gotwig/weekly
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/unstable-upstream
```

I tried to install it via:

```
sudo apt install indicator-synapse    
E: Unable to locate package indicator-synapse
```

Do you know an alternative to install this (or other old) indicator(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following command on your terminal. Then It will be OK.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-synapse
```

Then follow the following instruction:

**System Settings > Software & Updates > Other Software** > find and click noobslab/apps repository > Edit > change Distrbution value to "trusty". 
Then `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install indicator-synapse`. That's all.

Source: https://gist.github.com/brenopolanski/cb56125da4fede7a8abf

Comment: Thank you for your effort . Unfortunately I still get "E: Unable to locate package indicator-synapse" as response.

Comment: If you face problem with ubuntu 16.04, Then follow the following instruction:

System Settings > Software&Updates > Other Software > find and click noobslab/apps repository > Edit > change Distrbution value to "trusty". Then sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get install indicator-synapse.

Comment: Thank you so much, after changing the distrbution  in the noobslab/apps repository to 'trusty' via Other Software,  it works! However I had to reboot to launch the indicator.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:synapse-core/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synapse
```

Working on Ubuntu 16.04

[Source](http://www.techdrivein.com/2015/02/install-synapse-ubuntu-ppa.html)

Comment: Thank you for your effort, however this is not the indicator GUI that looks like spotlight.